# Cannot run PowerShell script in folder with square braces

Tags: powershell, path

I have a PowerShell script in a folder with square braces, for example:

When I try and run my script from the command line using:

```
C:\Temp\[test]>Powershell.exe .\MyScript.ps1
```

I get the following output:

[image]

If I put the same script in a folder without square braces and run:

```
C:\Temp\(test)>Powershell.exe .\MyScript.ps1
```

It works and I get the following output:

[image]

The script is part of an automation project and must be in a folder with square braces. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:** passing a local path to powershell.exe that includes square brackets in the folder names means that powershell cannot find the script file passed to it.

**Option 1:** use powershell -File .\MyScript.ps1
**Option 2:** use powershell %CD%\MyScript.ps1

I am not clear why powershell cannot find your path, but the -File command line argument seems to fix it. As does using the %CD% batch file property instead of '.'

If I create a file "HelloWorld.ps1" containing the single line:

```
Write-Output "Hello World"
```

in a folder

```
c:\work\joel\scream
```

and run the command:

```
C:\work\joel\scream>powershell .\HelloWorld.ps1
```

then I get the expected output (Hello World).

If I rename the folder to [scream], it fails.

```
cd ..
ren scream [scream]
```

Square brackets is a range operator.

```
C:\work\joel\[scream]>powershell .\HelloWorld.ps1
```

now yields:

> .\helloworld.ps1 : The term '.\helloworld.ps1' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
>   the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
>   again.

However running:

```
C:\work\joel\[scream]>powershell -File .\HelloWorld.ps1
```

gives the expected output (Hello World).

```
powershell /?
<snip/>
-File
    Runs the specified script in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the
    functions and variables that the script creates are available in the
    current session. Enter the script file path and any parameters.
    File must be the last parameter in the command, because all characters
    typed after the File parameter name are interpreted
    as the script file path followed by the script parameters.
```

I'm not clear whether powershell or the command prompt / batch script is misinterpreting the path but I can say that while:

```
C:\work\joel\[scream]>powershell .\HelloWorld.ps1
```

does not work:

```
C:\work\joel\[scream]>powershell %CD%\helloworld.ps1
```

does work. so it appears to be related to the expansion of '.' into the current path.

Comment: He is not using the square brackets in his command - there seem to be nothing to escape. It's the *current path* that contains square brackets.

Comment: Ok @zespri, I'll pay that, it isn't to do with powershell's usage of square brackets for ranges.

Comment: @zespri Understood that the brackets are in the path. However, the . expands to the current working directory, hence there are brackets in the command, indirectly. The correct answer is in the middle of his answer - use `powershell.exe -File .\MyScript.ps1`. I'm not sure, though, why `powershell -Command ".\MyScript.ps1"` doesn't work when `.\MyScript.ps1` works if typed at the prompt in a directory with brackets. I noticed that tab expansion also doesn't work in directories with brackets.